# What are some Household foods to mix with medicine?

Tags: medicines, treats, cat-food

Trying to give some feral cats dewormer medication, and need something that a feral cat will love to eat. One cat liked yogurt, but not so much another one. Anything that all cats adore and is cheap and readily available, like peanut butter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the taste of the medication (which *you* should never taste, of course!) a cat may never voluntarily swallow it. We've made some really bad experiences with dewormer tablets. First we smeared liver paste on it and stuffed it into the mouth of our cat. The liver paste was swallowed, the tablet was spit out. Then we crushed the tablet and mixed it with a lot of liver paste to dilute the taste. The cat refused to eat even a single bite. We had to buy a different dewormer with a different taste.

Apart from smearing a paste on the medicine, there are also "**pill pocket treats**" available that look and probably taste like regular cat food but have a hole to hide a pill inside. Rest assured that if the pill tastes bitter or has a smell the cat already associates with negative experiences, it won't help you at all. Cats are naturally finnicky eaters. But if the pill is neutral enouch, the cat will probably eat it with the treat.

To get a feral cat to eat these pocket treats, you should feed one or two empty treats for a few days before starting medication, to associate the smell and taste of them with positive experiences.

Another alternative is cutting a **wiener sausage** into small pieces and stuff the tablet in the middle of a piece. Works a lot like these pocket treats. The inside usually is soft enough to accomodate a pill without splitting the skin. If not, cut a thin sliver out of the center with the pointy tip of a knife.
As for pastes, the afore mentioned **liver paste** (aka liver paté) and **cream cheese** may work. Raw **ground beef** is also a possible alternative (no raw pork!). If you mash and kneed the ground meat for a few minutes in your hands the proteins get sticky (like gluten in a dough) and it's easier to stick it to a pill.

Answer (score 2):

If the medication can be mixed with liquids, like if it's a powder or liquid, then there are cat treats that are like a gravy or broth that are really perfect for this purpose, like [Fancy Feast broth.](https://www.chewy.com/fancy-feast-classic-collection-broths/dp/113933) It's also convenient because it's a liquid, the cats like to lick the dish clean, so you can really be sure they ate all of it.